# Gnuplot invisible

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot two implicit curves (using pgfplots and raw gnuplot) but they don't appear in the document.
In gnuplot it works just fine so I guess it has something to do with pgfplots but i can't figure out, what the problem is.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
unset key
set contour base;
set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
unset surface;
set view map;
set isosamples 50,50;
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
f(a,c) = a*cosh(c/a)-N
ell1(a,c) = (c/z)**2+(1/(1-cosh(z)))**2*(a-N/(cosh(z)))**2-(N/cosh(z))**2  
N = 1
z = 1.19968
splot f(x,y),ell1(x,y)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: add the missing `;` at the end of each command, then it should work

Comment: oh indeed. i thought they are optional as gnuplot didn't need them.
Do you want to answer this or shall i flag my question for deletion?

Comment: retain the question as it might look silly mistake ( sometimes silly can be brilliant) but someone may be in the same situation would benefit. I made the answer with the plot, hope it's the plot you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment into answer

If you notice `ur-file-name.pgf-plot.gnuplot` created by first `pdflatex -shell-escape ur-filename.tex` compilation there is a missing `;` at the end of each gnuplot command, then it may not work like in a terminal gnuplot(eg: command by command execution) as `;` command line terminator is *required* to separate the gnuplot commands when fed in a file to gnuplot.

```
\documentclass[convert=false,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[raw gnuplot] gnuplot {
unset key;
set contour base;
set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
unset surface;
set view map;
set isosamples 50,50;
set xrange [0:1];
set yrange [-1:1];
f(a,c) = a*cosh(c/a)-N;
ell1(a,c) = (c/z)**2+(1/(1-cosh(z)))**2*(a-N/(cosh(z)))**2-(N/cosh(z))**2;  
N = 1;
z = 1.19968;
splot f(x,y),ell1(x,y);
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]